How to route different ports to different pathnames on EC2 using nginx or any other service?
Suppose I want to map port :8000 to http://example.com/jan1po port :8080 to http://example.com/po02an and so on. And this will be done using a NodeJS process. That is http://example.com/jan1po will get routed to port :8000 of the EC2 machine and http://example.com/po02an will be routed to port :8080. And the NodeJS process will generate more such random pathnames and will bind to a port of the EC2 machine. How to implement this?
Normally a nginx reverse proxies all browser requests for a domain to same port that we define in the sites-available file. Tried finding solutions online but got all confused. If anyone could help it will be great.

If you want to expose Node.js web apps on port 8000 and 8080 to outside, then a reverse proxy like nginx is the right way to go. However, how to configure nginx for such simple scenarios belongs to tutorials and user manuals, and not directly programming related. I think this is off topic here.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Try this
server {
    server_name example.com;

    location /jan1po/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        ...
    }

    location /po02an/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        ...
    }
}

